# loading sqlite data into detailed view. Data does not change. Help

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I'm new to programming and I'm following a tutorial that loads data from sqlite database into a table (name) and then when selected loads detailed view showing more data (Address etc).

My problem is that when I first load the data in the detailed view it works fine however when I try to load data again on a another table item (name) the detailed view loads with the first lot of data and does not change until I restart the simulator. i.e.

first selection:
table "Name 1" push detailed view "Address 1" works fine.

second selection:
table "Name 2" push detailed view "Address 1" data does not change.

Here is my code;

-(void) hydrateDetailViewData {
    if (isDetailViewHydrated) return;

```
if (detailStmt == nil) {
    const char *sql = "Select ClubAddress from clubNames Where clubID = ?";
     if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &detailStmt, NULL) !=SQLITE_OK)
         NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating detail view statment. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
     }
sqlite3_bind_int(detailStmt, 1, clubID);

if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(detailStmt)) {
    const char *db_text = sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt, 0);
    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: db_text];
    self.ClubAddress = address;
}
else
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while getting the address of club. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
sqlite3_reset(detailStmt);

isDetailViewHydrated = YES;
}
```

I have tried releasing the variable but I get compiler warnings and the app crashes when I try to push detailed view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got some questions:

Are you getting the correct information from your query? Check that out by querying the db directly from the command line.

Are you presenting the data in table views? Table views don't refresh instantaneously. you should call [tableView reloadData] to do so. Check Table View Programming guide if you have further doubts with that.

Can you post the code snippet where you push the that ViewControllers that crash?

If you are getting crashes for releasing object, you'd better take a look at the memory management programming guide on the Developer documentation.

Comment: Yes I'm getting the correct info on the first query. Where would I place the [tableView reloadData] and how is it implemented.@Pacu

Comment: If you are pushing the view controller, then you have to put the reloadData call in -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method of your VC

Comment: How do you write [tableView reloadData] please@Pacu

Answer (score 0):

From your code you are setting isDetailViewHydrated to YES but do you ever set it to no?